# Do private keys work across chains and networks?

Tags: private-key, ecdsa

If I generate a private key on mainnet now, would I be able to use it at the same address on Ethereum Classic? What about testnets?

In what cases would the keys not give the same address on different networks / chains?

A follow up question would be: since deployed contract addresses are derived from nonce and sender address, does it mean if I deploy n contracts on different networks and chains, the n contracts would have the same set of addresses on different networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I generate a private key on mainnet now, would I be able to use it
>   at the same address on Ethereum Classic? What about testnets?

Yes, this is exactly how it works - Ethereum, ETC, and all the test nets (Ropsten, Kovan, Rinkeby) generate the address from the private key in the same way.  Also other Ethereum-based blockchains, such as [Expanse](https://expanse.tech/) or [Ubiq](https://ubiqscan.io/).

You can confirm this on [MEW](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info) by going to the View Wallet Info tab, and trying the same (arbitrary, e.g. 0x0101...0101) private key while attached to different networks: the address generated will be the same in each case.

> In what cases would the keys not give the same address on different networks / chains?

The address generation method is specified in the [Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io) appendix F. If the chain doesn't conform to this then  different addresses will be generated.

> A follow up question would be: since deployed contract addresses are
>   derived from nonce and sender address, does it mean if I deploy n
>   contracts on different networks and chains, the n contracts would have
>   the same set of addresses on different networks?

Again, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! The private/public key pairs and address work the same across the testnets/mainnet, as well as the same on the ETC network.

If the nonce is the same for the transactions on both networks, then yes, the contracts will have the same addresses. [Here's](https://medium.com/bitclave/how-we-sent-eth-to-the-wrong-address-and-successfully-recovered-them-2fc18e09d8f6) a good story from a few weeks ago regarding exactly this.